# CSS id and class rules, best option to have its own whole div without individual class

Tags: html, css

I would like to know which would be the best method to create the table in its own div, just affecting itself, using the CSS.

I'm not sure which would be better to keep it in its own individual div.

```
<head>
<title>f.f. timetable</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.fightingfitlondon.co.uk/files/theme/timetable.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fftime" class="ff">
<table class="ff">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Monday</th>
  <th>Tuesday</th>
  <th>Wednesday</th>
  <th>Thursday</th>
  <th>Friday</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>07:50&nbsp;- 08:35</td>
  <td rowspan="5">Sprint Training</td>
  <td>Sparring</td>
  <td rowspan="5">Class 1</td>
  <td rowspan="5">Class 2</td>
  <td rowspan="5">Class 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">08:45&nbsp;- 10:30</td>
  <td rowspan="2">Skipping</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">10:40&nbsp;- 12:20</td>
  <td rowspan="2">Boxing</td>
   </tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="6"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td rowspan="2">13:25&nbsp;- 15:05</td>
   <td rowspan="4">Private Lesson</td>
   <td rowspan="2">Running Session</td>
   <td rowspan="4">Class 4</td>
   <td rowspan="4">Class 5</td>
   <td rowspan="4">Class 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">15:20&nbsp;- 17:00</td>
  <td rowspan="2">Conditioning</td>
   </tr>
   <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Css**

I can't seem to figure out which would be the best placements for the id selector.

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);

 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 }

 html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
  }

 table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  thead th,
  tbody td:first-child:not([colspan="6"]) {
  background: #456;
   color: white;
  }

  tbody tr td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
 }

  tbody td:not(:first-child) {
   background: #EEF;
 }

  tbody td:not(:first-child):hover {
    background: #E8E8FF;
  }

  td[colspan="6"] {
   height: 5px;
   padding: 0;
 }

 th, td {
   width: 18.5%;
   padding: 1%;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   text-align: center;
   }

  th:first-child,
  td:first-child {
  width: 7.5%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limtu

Reading your comments you're using global CSS rules which are the actual tag names such as table, th, thead so this will add styles to all your tables

Here is an example, hope this will help you out understand CSS rules

HTML:

```
 <div class="tableWrapper">
 <table id="tableID">
 <thead>

 </thead>
 <tbody class="tableBody">
 <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .tableBody tr: nth-child(even) 
  {
       border-color: green;
  }

  .tableBody tr:nth-child(odd)
  {
       border-color: blue; 
   }
```

Comment: Thankyou Chris - i need to brush up on this. Thanks very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would set out my table if it was going into it's own 'div' tag

```
<div id="AppendTableID/TableWrapperID">
     <table id="tableID" class="className">
     <thead>
     </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

**Example 1:**

```
#tableID
{
   //CSS
}
```

**Example 2**

```
#tableID.className 
{
  //CSS
}
```

Comment: ah yes, thankyou. althought for the css im not sure how to style the whole div by just using the id selector in css, so it doesnt clash with other similar ids and tags used in other elements.

Comment: @Limtu I've changed my answer to give you two examples of the CSS

Comment: #fftime {

 background-color: #c90e0e;
 
}

#ff.ffstyle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


#ff.ffstyle thead, tbody td:first-child:not([colspan="6"]) 

{

  background: #456;
  color: white;
  
  }

Comment: but it still affects other <thead>, i cant seem to get it to only effect the table. it still affects other tags. e.g. when i change css to the <thead> it changes all <thead> on other tables, just want to contain the correct css to the correct table div. very confusing haha

Answer (score 0):

```
 Below sort of works, but just shows structure



    #ff.ffstyle {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   }

   #ff html, #ff body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   }

    #ff table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #ff thead #ff th,
    #ff tbody #ff td:first-child:not([colspan="6"]) {
    background: #456;
    color: white;
    }

    #ff tbody #ff tr #ff td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    }

   #ff tbody #ff td:not(:first-child) {
   background: #EEF;
    }

   #ff tbody #ff td:not(:first-child):hover {
   background: #E8E8FF;
   }

   #ff td[colspan="6"] {
   height: 5px;
   padding: 0;
   }

   #ff th, #ff td {
   width: 18.5%;
   padding: 1%;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   text-align: center;
   }

   #ff th:first-child,
   #ff td:first-child {
   width: 7.5%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, although the last  tag is still reflecting in and effecting my nav menu which has the  tag

```
#ff .ffstyle {
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

 #ff html, body {
  height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
 }

  #ff table {
     width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
     border-collapse: collapse;
    }

     #ff thead th,
       #ff tbody td:first-child:not([colspan="6"]) {
        background: #456;
         color: white;
       }

       #ff tbody tr td:first-child {
       text-align: left;
     }

    #ff tbody td:not(:first-child) {
       background: #EEF;
     }

    #ff tbody td:not(:first-child):hover {
        background: #E8E8FF;
       }

         #ff td[colspan="6"] {
        height: 5px;
        padding: 0;
   }
      <!--this tag below, still affecting my nav menu even though its id is
       #ff-->
      #ff th, td {
       width: 18.5%;
      padding: 1%;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
       text-align: center;
        }

     #ff th:first-child,
     td:first-child {
     width: 7.5%;
    }
```